# Direction of gradient unit vector at r

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

Consider the scalar field in two dimensions f (x,y) = x2 + 4y2. This field has a global minimum at
r = (0, 0). Write a computer program in which, starting from the initial point r(0) = (4, 1.5), you try
to reach the minimum of the field by taking small steps ∆t along the negative direction of the local
gradient, which is defined by n = −∇f/|∇f|.

I'm having a hard time understanding what is being asked, am I supposed to start at n(4,1.5) and iterate until I reach n(0,0)? Which doesn't really make sense

Comment: [$\tt MathJax$ Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to be used in MSE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Start by writing the function as a matrix-vector equation
and calculating its gradient
$$\eqalign{
A &= \m{1&0\\0&4}, \qquad &x = \m{x\\y} \\
f(x) &= x^TAx \qiq &g(x)=\n\!f = 2Ax \\
}$$
Then apply a gradient descent iteration like the following.

Initialization
$$\eqalign{
x_0 &= \m{4\\1.5} \qquad g_0 = g(x_0)= \m{8\\12} \quad \\
}$$
First step
$$\eqalign{
x_1 &= x_0 - 10^{-3}g_0 \quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \\
g_1 &= g(x_1) \\
}$$
Subsequent steps
$$\eqalign{
x_{k+1} &= x_{k}
- \left[
   \frac{(x_k-x_{k-1})^T(g_k-g_{k-1})}{(g_k-g_{k-1})^T(g_k-g_{k-1})}
 \right]\c{g_k} \\
g_{k+1} &= g(x_{k+1}) \\
{\rm if}\,\big(g_{k+1}&\approx 0\big)\quad {\rm then\;exit}  \\
}$$
The expression in brackets that multiplies the gradient $(\c{g_k})$ is the steplength which characterizes the *Barzilai-Borwein* method.

Alternatively, you could use fixed steplengths or calculate an optimal steplength via line-searches, but this simple expression is surprisingly effective.

Answer (score 0):

Start off at vector $r_0=(4,1.5)$. The direction of decrease is in direction of $\nabla f(r_0)$. So, $\Delta t(\nabla f(r_0))$ would be a small change in direction of minimum. So, $r_1=r_0-\Delta t(\nabla f(r_0))$ would be a position vector a little closer to the minimum than $r_0$ was. By defining successive $r_n=r_{n-1}-\Delta t(\nabla f(r_{n-1}))$, you can get successively closer to the minimum.